# Dart runtimeType not returning correct type

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, dart

```
void main() {
  final list = [1].cast<int>();
  print('${list.runtimeType}'); // prints CastList<int, int>
}
```

When I type `lis...`, Android Studio code completion infers the type as `List<int>` which it is but when I use `runtimeType` on it, it prints `CastList<int, int>`.

Is this IDE fault or Dart?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cast`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/List/cast.html) method is specified to return a List:

> `List<R> cast <R>()`

So this is what your IDE are based on since this is the only guarantee your get. But since other classes can extend/implement `List`, we are also allowed to return a class which extends from `List` and return objects based on this new type of `List`.

E.g. in you example we can see that `cast` actually returns an instance of `CastList`. But since `CastList` implements the interface of `List` the `cast` method are allowed to return the `CastList` instance.

And this is one of the reason why you should never really use `runtimeType` for anything other than debugging. `runtimeType` will return the specific type of the object without any details about implemented interfaces.

Instead, you should use the `is` operator if you want to test for a given type like:

```
if (obj is List<int>)
```

The `is` operator will test if `obj` implements the interface of e.g. `List<int>` and not just test if `obj` is created from this specific class.

Comment: Using `List<int> list;` and then using `list.runtimeType` returns `List<int>`.

Comment: Second, sometimes it isn't possible to use `is`, because I don't know the type of a variable which is `dynamic`, so is makes no sense in that case, because I actually want to know the type. `is` is only useful when you have few options to guess.

Comment: Where did I say that `List` is not a class which is implemented in Dart? A better example would be map where `Map<String, int> map = {'one': 1}; print(map.runtimeType);` will print "_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, int>"

Comment: About `runtimeType` I did say you should only use it for debugging like e.g. you want to see that type it is. But when you know the types, you should write you code to use `is` to make correct type casts and type checks as much as possible so you can use the Dart type system.

Comment: `Where did I say that List is not a class which is implemented in Dart` when did I say that? And on using `runtimeType` on `Map`, it does give you `<String, int>` but in my code a list is showing you map type syntax `<int, int>`

Comment: I am using `runtimeType` for debugging but I don't know the types, then shouldn't I use `runtimeType` to know the `Type`?

Comment: The problem with `runtimeType` is it is telling the raw true about the type on runtime but that is rarely what we want when we program since we are more interested in interfaces. I am guessing you gets your `dynamic` from some JSON parsing and I will suggest you look at the JSON itself to see what is List or Map when parsing. `dynamic` is something you should keep at a bare minimum in your code base.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214560/discussion-between-julemand101-and-ikeepchangingname).